# What to include for cv::meanShift function?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I've included the following and it doesn't work :

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
```

What to include for `cv::meanShift` function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 hours later I found the answer :)

For some reason #include  can't be included directly so the following code will include the video module indirectly.

```
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp"
```

Answer here : http://fossies.org/dox/opencv-2.4.9/video_8hpp.html

Answer (score 1):

it's in the [video](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#meanshift) module, so:

```
#include <opencv2/video/video.hpp>
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work ... it doesn't recognize #include <opencv2/video/video.hpp>. I also added opencv_video220d.lib and opencv_video220.lib to aditional dependencies. Any ideea why ? :(

Comment: though 2.2 is stone-age, it should be [there](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_attic/blob/2.2/opencv/modules/video/include/opencv2/video/tracking.hpp#L267)

Comment: also, please add only *1* lib, the d one for debug, and without for release, and never mix them !!

Comment: <opencv/video/tracking.hpp> for 2.2 ?